# R 3.0.0 crashes on startup

Tags: r, crash

I just updated R from version 2.15.1 to version 3.0.0 on my MAC running 10.6.8 and now R crashes on startup.

I get the error:

> Error in getLoadedDLLs() : there is no .Internal function 'getLoadedDLLs'
>   Error in checkConflicts(value) :
>    ".isMethodsDispatchOn" is not a BUILTIN function

Any ideas on how to go about?

Comment: Probably your new R version is picking up old versions of either the old base R code, or of installed packages. Or you are starting the old version of R which picks up new code in some way. Have you re-installed all your packages?

Comment: I think this was discussed on the list -- obviously, you can simply remove your .RData (`rm ~/.RData` in Terminal), but AFAIR the latest R 3.0.0-patched (you can get it from http://r.research.att.com/) is supposed to fix the crash.

Answer (score 2):

The most common cause of this is having a corrupted ".Rdata" file in your working directory. Using the Mac Finder.app you will not  by default be able to see files that begin with a ".", so-called dotfiles. Those files can be "seen" if you execute a change to the plist controlling the behavior of Finder.app. Open a Terminal.app window and run this bit of code:

```
defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles YES
```

Then /point/-/click/-/hold/ on Dock-Finder-icon, and choose "Relaunch"

If you to do so, you can then change it back with the obvious modfication to that procedure. I happen to like seeing the hidden files so that's the way I run my Mac all the time, but some people may feel it is too dangerous to expose the "hidden secrets" to their own bumbling.

Paul raises a good point: I run the following R function in the R console after updating:

```
update.packages(checkBuilt=TRUE, ask=FALSE)
```

I have a lot of installed packages and paging through the entire list has gotten too tiresome so I bypass the ask-messages. Sometimes you will get errors because there may be dependencies on r-forge or Omegahat packages or on packages that need to be compiled from source. These may need to be updated "by hand". And you may need more than one pass through such an effort. Take notes of which packages are missing and fill them in.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem running RKWard on ubuntu 12.04.
Check your r-base-core, like Paul suggested, to make sure the version is also at the latest version. Mine didn't update automatically. I had a platform dependent version, but RKWard was calling the new version. To solve this problem, I simply marked r-base-core for removal and reinstalled the latest version or r-base-core. poof problem fixed, bippity boppity boo!

I suspect that your error is similar to mine because I had also JUST updated RKWard. Start at updating r-base-core or try to get all of the dependencies to match up the versions.

I hope that you can translate this into what to do on a MAC,
   SU